# FuelPHP - Loading Models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, models, fuelphp

this is most likely a simple answer that i have overlooked..

I am trying to create a customer controller that accesses a custom model in FuelPHP as follows:

```
class Controller_Casting extends Controller
{
   public function action_index()
   {
      Model_casting::author_get();
   }
}

class Model_casting
{
   ## --------------------
   public function author_get()
   {
      $query = DB::query('SELECT * FROM youtube_author');
      $result = $query->execute(); 
      print_r($result);     
   }   
}
```

An error is generated by the controller:

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'Model_casting' not found
```

In code igniter i would have to load the model before using it.. How do you do the same thing in FuelPHP (which i presume is where the issue lies)..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also one more thing. If class names should always be formatted like Model_Casting. First letter uppercase and after a '_' also uppercased. Just a tip!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved it would seem.. I was prefixing the model with "model"..

Answer (score 0):

You need use namespace Model and DB, try to extends Model class.
This is the new code for Model file.

```
namespace Model;
use \DB;
class Model_Casting extends \Model
{
   ## --------------------
   public function author_get()
   {
      $query = DB::query('SELECT * FROM youtube_author');
      $result = $query->execute(); 
      print_r($result);     
   }   
}
```

Comment: You don't have to namespace models if you don't want to. But if you do, this is not the way, it will create \Model\Model_Casting in ./classes/model/model/casting.php. So if you opt for namespacing, you can drop the "Model_" prefix in the classname.